# JPQL/HQL delete query with spring data jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

I'm not really familiar with JPQL/HQL, so the question might be a bit dumb, I'm trying to write a delete query with string jpa.

I have `GeneratedStatement` object which has `GeneratedStatementId` object which consists of `createdDate`.

My query should look something like this:

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM EODGeneratedStatement s WHERE s.createdDate < :expiryDate")
int deleteByIdCreatedDateBefore(LocalDate expiryDate);
```

But I think it lacks the GeneratedStatementId object in it, and I'm not sure how to add it. It should be like s.getGeneratedStatementId().createdDate something I believe

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an `@Entity` named `GeneratedStatement` which has `GeneratedStatementId` POJO object in it which contain variable `createdDate`.

If you are looking for a `@OneToOne` Mapping between `GeneratedStatement` and `GeneratedStatementId`, below query should work.

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM GeneratedStatement s left join 
                        s.GeneratedStatementId sid WHERE sid.createdDate < :expiryDate")
int deleteByIdCreatedDateBefore(LocalDate expiryDate);
```

`@OneToOne` Mapping and `FetchType` is `Lazy`,

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM GeneratedStatement s left join fetch 
                        s.GeneratedStatementId sid WHERE sid.createdDate < :expiryDate")
```